# Interpretation of the word "immediately" in Phase 3 or Phase 4

Tags: rivals-for-catan

My opponent pulled the Trade Master card during phase 3.  Because the card has the word "immediately" on it, she believed that she could play it.  Yet the rules say that in phase 3 you cannot play it.  Can she play this card during phase 3 or phase 4?

Answer (score 2):

I can't see any reason why Trade Master would circumvent the normal rules for playing an Action.  I think all that the "immediately" implies is that, when you play the card during phase 2, you get the resources straightaway at that point.

Why this particular card would use the word "immediately" when all action cards are specified by the rules as taking "immediate effect" isn't very clear - but in situations like this I usually assume a slightly loose translation from the original German, rather than reading a special meaning in.  Perhaps a native speaker could tell us what the wording on the German cards are?

Answer (score 2):

The [rules](http://www.catan.com/en/download/?RfC-CG-Rules-092710.pdf) explain the Trade Master card a bit better.

> If you play the Trade Master card, choose 2 resources that the opponent must give you.

The first clause makes it clear that this card cannot be played at any time and follows the normal conventions of playing it within your Action phase (phase 2).